# Tomcat won't start from within Eclipse after stripping project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have been stripping down a Spring MVC Eclipse/Maven project to get a bare minimal example of certain functionality, but the process of stripping out files has resulted in an error that causes Tomcat not to launch.

How can I resolve this error so that Tomcat will launch and the app can run in a web browser from within Eclipse?

I have not made changes to server.xml, or to any of the other Tomcat config files.  I was able to launch tomcat and run this project numerous times during the strip down process, so I think the problem has to do with something missing from the project.  **Other projects in the workspace are able to `Run As...Run on server` successfully**, thus pointing the cause of the problem to something inside this project.  However, the one line in `server.xml` that refers to this project is:

```
<Context docBase="NoClassDefFoundError" path="/NoClassDefFoundError" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NoClassDefFoundError"/></Host>
```

The complete stack trace of the error is:

```
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NoClassDefFoundError]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NoClassDefFoundError]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    ... 20 more

Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Apr 17, 2015 9:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NoClassDefFoundError]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5427)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:272)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:603)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: I downloaded the project from the link that you provided. I did `mvn clean install` and then selected **Run on server** in eclipse. The server started successfully and displayed the **Click On This Link to reproduce the ERROR** page. When I clicked on the link, it displayed a page with text **If you can see this text, then the ERROR has been resolved.**. Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: I have successfully started the project using IntelliJ without any modifications to the code.
However, a ClassDefNotError is usally the result of some runtime dependencies not being picked up when assembling the war-file. Check if all necessary libraries are packed into the war file.

Comment: I was also able to run it without modification in Eclipse with "run on server". I used/assumed tomcat 7, since you didn't specify. You could look into several possible directions: You have numerous spring version "conflicts". You're managing the depencency between major versions (3 vs 4). Since it's a classpath issue, maybe there are non standard libs in the shared/common directories? That shouldn't really be a a problem though, so I suspect Eclipse is at fault.

Comment: @Mithun Oddly, turning off my devbox and then restarting the next day resolved the problem. However, before I posted, `project clean`, `mvn update projects`, and `mvn download sources` did not fix the problem, no matter now many times I tried. Since yours is the first and most logical solution, I would be happy to mark yours as the answer if you choose to submit it. Thank you.  I will remember `mvn clean install` in the future. Can you please explain why `mvn clean install` works when the others do not? What is `mvn clean install` doing with this specific `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run `mvn clean install` before running the project in the server. `clean` makes sure that all the files generated from the previous build are deleted and `install` makes sure that the generated archive file is put into your local repository

I downloaded the project from the link that you provided. I did `mvn clean install` and then selected `Run on server` in eclipse.

The server started successfully and displayed the **Click On This Link to reproduce the ERROR** page. When I clicked on the link, it displayed a page with text **If you can see this text, then the ERROR has been resolved**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I always kept remembering while developing webapps with Eclipse

1. any change on the file system outside Eclipse, sometimes even when running maven build, is not automatically picked up. Right click -> refresh on the project does it
2. tomcat publishing works *shady*, as in sometimes it doesn't either publish all the necessary resources or correctly cleanup the previous deploy, and I couldn't figure out why. It could be related to [windows locking files](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Avoiding+JAR+and+file+locking+under+Windows) but I had this happening while using [`antiJARLocking=true` or `antiResourceLocking=true`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard%20Implementation) so I'm not 100% sure

Anyway, when this used to happen in my project, I'd do the following which usually fixed it:

- stop tomcat
- refresh, clean & build the project
- do a clean publish towards tomcat
- start tomcat

**EDIT**

When it happens again, you can check out what files have been deployed by looking (by default) in the workspace under `metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`. You can check this path to see if it's locked with [Process Explorer to see if the files were locked with CTRL+F](https://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file) or with a similar tool of your choice.

Comment: This does not even address the question.  Please delete this response unless you are going to actually answer the question.  Any answer to the question will require you to download the sample project in the OP and then demonstrate SPECIFICALLY IN CODE what needs to be changed IN THE SPECIFIC DOWNLOADED PROJECT in order to get it running, as described above.

Comment: @CodeMed everyone is entitled to their own opinion and I respect that. Nonetheless, while I may be wrong, given that the sample works perfectly as other people also pointed out, I would think the problem could & may be somewhere else than **SPECIFICALLY IN THE CODE**, wouldn't you agree? Hence my reply, which is based on my previous experiences with eclipse & webapps, attempts to provide a different perspective to your problem. You also said it worked after restarting & your classes have CRLF terminators, so the `windows locking files` link or suspecting eclipse may hold some truth after all.

Comment: `mvn clean install` is an example of a code solution that I accepted.  Also, the person downloaded the sample project, which is stated as a requirement.  You did neither.  Also, you incorrectly assume that windows has anything to do with it.  This is not a windows question.  The OP never mentions windows.  This is a cross platform eclipse/java question.  The devbox happens to be linux, which is just as irrelevant to the question as is your assumption of windows. You did not answer the question.  You provided only comments, which belong in the comments section only.

Comment: Please see this meta posting about why not to post comments like yours as answers.  The correct place for comments like yours is in the comments attached to the OP. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible

Comment: @CodeMed I'm sorry my answer does not meet your expectations and I'm happy that `mvn clean install` works for you. While it will clean the output folder and rebuild you project (also installing the artifact in your local repo),  as I said I sometimes had issues with eclipse correctly publishing the resources to tomcat after running the maven build. I fail to see why it was required to download the project while others commented it works, which made me believe you have the same issue . Even if it's not windows, I still believe my answer is valid and I'm happy to provide more detail is needed.

Comment: @CodeMed please note that neither my answer nor creating a run configuration with `maven clean install` are *code solutions* and they also intersect somewhere. I guess what I'm trying to say is that not all solutions are code based and sometimes we have to look elsewhere. Cheers